# I can't find a way to make a flashing cursor effect?

Tags: animation

I was trying to make a title screen where it was like a flashing typing cursor. Any ideas to create that effect?

Comment: It would be helpful to add images or find an example of this effect to make it clear to other people what effect you are referencing.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link and add more information to your question. Is this a 3D scene you are doing? If so please specify what render engine. Or are you trying to create this on the VSE or Compositor? Please clarify.

Comment: Easy. Use a generated sine wave on the objects opacity, and have a limits modifier clip it. Doodle around in the graph editor, you will figure it out

Answer (score 4):

In Cycles you may achieve it (if I got you right) animating the *Factor* value between ***Emission*** and ***Transparent*** nodes.
[image]

Add your *text* with dash and convert it to mesh with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>-->*Mesh from Text*. Select the dash and give it a material using *material nodes* as pictured below (mix ***Emission*** and ***Transparent*** shaders).
[image]

Go to frame ***1*** on a *Timeline* and press <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering the cursor over the *Fac* slider of the ***Mix*** shader (set it's value to ***0.000*** before). It'll add a keyframe to it.
[image]

Go to the frame ***10*** (or any further one), change the *Fac* value to ***1.000*** and insert the keyframe again.
[image]

Now go to frame ***20***, change the Mix value to ***0.000*** and repeat the keyframing process.
[image]

To extend the animation go to the ***NLA Editor*** and press the *'double down arrows'* symbol there.
[image]

Finally open the *properties panel* there (<kbd>N</kbd>) and set the ***Scale*** and ***Repeat*** values. *Scale*'ll increase the blinking lenght and *Repeat*'ll extend the whole animation.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That can also be done with Animation Nodes addon (https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases):

[image]

The setting:

- Frame as input
- Modulo a value to tune the rhythm
- Compare to the middle value (for instance) to drive the object visibility

This previous setup is at the object level, so, independent to rendering mode.

But you can also drive a material (Cycles here):

[image]

The principle:

- The material is lead by a mix shader (top right)
- The mix shader input is available as Cycles material output in AN (bottom part, on the right)
- And this output is driven by the frame (like before)