# Making a cursor (caret) that leads the typing effect using animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to simulate a dos prompt screen.  using the text nodes in animation nodes I have the act of typing simulated. However is there a way to have a cursor box automatically lead the text, or is this something I am stuck manually simulating with keyframes.

Comment: What have you tried? I would expect periodic hiding/showing of the caret to work just fine.

Comment: Using animation nodes I haven’t tried anything, I cant think of how to get the caret in front of the text being typed.  I have manually key-framed the location, but I am going to add a lot more text, and am wondering if I can automate the Caret to lead all the typing instead of manually key-framing as it would speed up the process

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74304/i-cant-find-a-way-to-make-a-flashing-cursor-effect/74311#74311

Comment: Yes thats a relevant link to make a cursor blink. I was more concerned witb the appearance of text being typed and leading the text with the cursor box. I will remove the blink from my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it, first I needed to use windows character map to find the Box character, and also a font that has that character, I chose Ariel. here is the node tree I used and works like I needed. Hopefully others find this usefull.
[image]